# CSS Flexbox formatting with <p>

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the [following jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremydr2/x3aqpc5z/8/):

```css
.links {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <address class="links">
    <p>
    Jeremy is on:
    </p>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
      LinkedIn
    </a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/5889131/jeremysprofile">
      Stack Overflow
    </a>
  </address>
</body>

</html>
```

The output looks like:

```
              LinkedIn Stack Overflow
Jeremy is on:
```

I don't understand why. I expect all the elements to be on the same line (or have the later elements wrap underneath, not the first element).

I noted that this happens with a `<p>` or a `<h1>` tag, but not a `<div>` tag on the "Jeremy is on" line. I looked at the default CSS settings for [`<p>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) and [`<div>`](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_div.asp), but I didn't see anything obvious. I tried making some CSS changes with `.p { margin: none; display: inline-flex;}` but it didn't make a difference.

**Why** does a `<p>` tag get put underneath the links, and a `<div>` tag not? What CSS rules can I apply to make a `<p>` tag behave like a `<div>` tag in this section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few errors in your CSS. You reference a `.p` class, when you mean to reference the element directly, `p`. Also, `none` is an invalid value for the `margin` property. The invalid `margin` value is why the `p` is appearing to be underneath the links. This is because of the `margin` that is not being removed as you had expected.

[image]

Change this:

```
.p {
  margin: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

To this:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also, for nicer formatting where the items fill the entire line, I would change `inline-flex` to `flex`:

```
.links {
  display: flex;
  …
}
```

```css
.links {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-style: normal;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<address class="links">
  <p>Jeremy is on:</p>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
    LinkedIn
  </a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/5889131/jeremysprofile">
    Stack Overflow
  </a>
</address>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwjm0zfy/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to change the < p > to < span >

If you want to it in CSS you need to remove the . from the p style as this is looking for a class called p and not the element also "none" is not valid for margin, you will need to change it to "unset" or 0 instead